# How to clean zend_cache from multiple server?

Tags: zend-framework, load-balancing, zend-cache

My site is located on two servers (i.e. `web01.mydomain.com` and `web02.mydomain.com`) under load balancing. I am using `zend_cache` for caching purpose, the cache is also located on both servers.

The issue is that when I try to clean my cache using below command it will only remove it from one server. I am using following command to remove the cache:

```
$cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);
```

Can you please explain how to remove cache from both servers?

Comment: An idea : By a cli php command on each server...

Comment: Cleaning option I have provided in the web interface. so when admin try to remove cache, it removes from same server from which request is coming.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in PHP & ZF... Maybe you will have to change some config in the load balancer, to force a given request to be sent on each servers...

Comment: What backend do you use and are the server/zend_cache instances both configured the same?